# How do I get rid of the ellipsis in Pycharm console and display information instead using Quandl?

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-console, quandl

I am working with Quandl in Pycharm. I tried to get information from the web and display it on the console; however, when I try to print the data, it shows an ellipsis instead. This problem only happens when using Pycharm. In the Python console connected to my PATH, it works properly. I tried changing the character length output on the console and making the lines wrap around to have more space, but nothing I tried worked. Thanks for the help.

### This is the code/ input

```
import quandl
df = quandl.get('WSE/TSGAMES', authtoken="JMx9w7AXwPfKAfJqmhDd")
print(df.head())
```

### This is Pycharm's output

This is what is displayed in Pycharm.

```
             Open  High       ...         # of Trades  Turnover (1000)
Date                          ...                                     
2018-05-11  52.20  63.0       ...              2026.0         11087.89
2018-05-14  68.00  74.8       ...              2655.0         16844.68
2018-05-15  66.60  66.6       ...              1279.0          5800.26
2018-05-16  63.50  63.9       ...               496.0          2119.90
2018-05-17  63.87  63.9       ...               358.0          1469.62
```

### This is PATH's output

This is what is displayed in Windows Python PATH.
I want THIS outcome in Pycharms console.

```
         Open  High    Low  Close  %Change    Volume  # of Trades  Turnover (1000)
Date
2018-05-11  52.20  63.0  51.11  62.00    34.78  200776.0       2026.0         11087.89
2018-05-14  68.00  74.8  65.30  66.70     7.58  240228.0       2655.0         16844.68
2018-05-15  66.60  66.6  58.28  62.00    -7.05   93961.0       1279.0          5800.26
2018-05-16  63.50  63.9  60.01  63.67     2.69   34008.0        496.0          2119.90
2018-05-17  63.87  63.9  59.00  59.00    -7.33   24068.0        358.0          1469.62
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing Panda, you need to set the max columns to something greater than 5 (which is the default when it can't detect the window size, which ends up happening in PyCharm).  Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)  # set this number to >= your number of cols

df = quandl.get('WSE/TSGAMES', authtoken="JMx9w7AXwPfKAfJqmhDd")

print(df.head())
```

Comment: I tried this and it still gives me the same three dots...